# Where are the AND and BUT keywords in cucumber library

Tags: angular, cucumber

I've just installed these libraries in an Angular project:

```
"@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.2.1",
"@types/chai": "^4.2.16",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "^8.0.2",
```

If I open the cucumber types there are no BUT or AND keywords:

[image]

How can I get it. Is there another library to install I am not aware?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The And and But keywords are only available in Gherkin documents. For Step Definitions, use Given, When or Then.

Comment: Is there any way to translate a feature's BUT into a step definition's THEN?

Comment: @dmance - steps beginning with `But` should automatically be recognized as `Then` steps. If this is not happening for you, please add information to your question.